# How to write this Lisp / Scheme code?

Tags: lisp, scheme

A lambda expression which takes a function (of one argument) and a number, and applies the function to twice the number.

Answer (score 9):

Applying the function to twice the number:

```
(lambda (f x) (f (* 2 x)))
```

Applying the function to the number twice (which is what you may have intended to ask):

```
(lambda (f x) (f (f x)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Greg's answer is correct, but you might think about how you might break apart this problem to find the answer yourself. Here is one approach:

```
; A lambda expression
;(lambda () )

; which takes a function (of one argument) and a number
;(lambda (fun num) )

; and applies the function
;(lambda (fun num) (fun num))

; to twice the number
;(lambda (fun num) (fun (* 2 num)))

((lambda (fun num) (fun (* 2 num))) + 12)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to approach it:

Write a Contract, Purpose, and Header:

```
;; apply-double : function -> number -> any
;; to apply a given function to double a given number
(define (apply-double fun num) ...)
```

Write some Tests:

```
(= (apply-double identity 10) 20)
(= (apply-double - 15) -30)
(= (apply-double / 7) 1/14)
```

Define the function:

```
(define (apply-double fun num) 
  (fun (* 2 num)))
```

This is an abbreviation of the recipe here: http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/